# How to compile C++ code in VSC using gcc on Mac?

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-studio-code, clang, macos-catalina

I'm new to coding so please forgive me if I've asked something too obvious.

I'm trying to set up **Visual Studio Code** (Version 1.46.1) on my Mac running Catalina (10.15.4), and I want to build my **C++ code using gcc**. I understand that Mac uses **Clang** and since I want to get into **Competitive Coding**, I'd prefer if **gcc** was used in VSC when I build my code. How do I do that?

I've tried following the documentation as well as various YouTube videos but I can't find anything given in a simple structure. Also, I wanted to make sure that I was using C++ 17 and not any other version.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't understand what GCC has to do with "competitive coding" (which I personally still think is a horrible way to teach people how to write bad code), but in order to compile C++ code using VSCode you need to either set up your tasks.json file or use a build system plugin for something like CMake

Comment: The official documentation already has examples for all OSes, you just need to set the `"command"` with the path to your desired compiler (see: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-linux#_build-helloworldcpp and https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac#_build-helloworldcpp)